# The SmartSource Data collector JavaScript Tag, could be inserted from Java?

Tags: javascript, java, webtrends

I'm totally new in Webtrends, I have read that The SmartSource Data collector JavaScript Tag, could be inserted from Java or HTML. does anyone know how to inser it from Java, I found the below class, is this class does the job? please provide some samples. Thanks in advance

```
public class DC {
public DC() {
    super();
}

public String post_url(String connUrl, Map<String, String> bodyref) {
    String response = "";
    String responseCode = "";

    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        // construct data
        String data = "";
        Iterator<String> i = bodyref.keySet().iterator();
        boolean ampersand = false;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            if (ampersand) {
                data += "&";
            } else {
                ampersand = true;
            }
            String b = i.next();
            data += b + "=" + bodyref.get(b);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[Request]");
        System.out.println("(Url)");
        System.out.println(connUrl);
        System.out.println("(Body)");
        System.out.println(data);

        // send data
        URL url = new URL(connUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        try {
            // get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
                response += "\n";
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            if (conn != null) {
                // get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                    response += "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[Response]");
        System.out.println("(Status)");
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("(Message)");
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("(Body)");
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.flush();

        wr.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[Response]");
        System.out.println("(Status)");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println("(Message)");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.flush();
    }

    return response;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DC dc = new DC();

    // customer-specific DCSID
    String dcsid = "dcslbiart00000gwngvpqkrcn_2u3z";

    // base portion of DC API url
    String base_url = "http://dc.webtrends.com/v1/" + dcsid;

    // post body
    Map<String, String> body1 = new HashMap();

    // post query string
    String querystring = "";

    // compose urls
    String id_url = base_url + "/ids.svc" + querystring;
    String event_url = base_url + "/events.svc" + querystring;

    // get visitor identifier
    String id = dc.post_url(id_url, body1);

    // post body
    Map<String, String> body = new HashMap();

    // initialize post body
    body.put("dcsuri", "/MyJavaTest");
    body.put("dcssip", "localhost");
    body.put("WT.ti", "MyJavaTest");
    body.put("WT.co_f", id);
    body.put("dcsverbose", "true");

    // submit event data
    dc.post_url(event_url, body);
}
```